# How to quickly merge a LOT (and i mean a LOT) of footage?

Tags: video, conversion, vlc

As the title says, we had an event recently and I plan to make a movie with the video from the event captured by four separate cameras. The files are ~500kb each. There are four folders, each with about 15000 files. I'd like to make one video per folder.

I've tried putting them in a storyboard in Windows Photos and I'm currently trying to Open Multiple Files - Convert with VLC. My i7-4770 is having a hard time with it, the files are on my Samsung 860 EVO SSD but this is still taking forever.

Anyone have any bright ideas?

Comment: I assume all files in a folder have the same media properties. If so, see ffmpeg's concat demuxer - https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate#demuxer

Comment: Hey Gyan, thanks for responding. I'm running the batch file now, the list creation worked like a charm so I assume the actual concatenation will also work. Thanks again!

Comment: Hey Gyan, hope you have another answer for me. I got a file from my smaller files that showed the most of what I was looking for, but not all of it. I got the error "pts has no value" a lot, should I assign a pts to my command? I ran a batch script from the source folder that was:

ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i mylist.txt -c copy videofile.mp4

Comment: Does the output play fine?

Comment: Thanks for responding. No, I'm missing about two hours of footage and some of it is very laggy. I've tried outputting it to AVI now, my theory last night was that it's just too much footage for mp4/m4a or some of the files are too short.

Comment: @Gyan I'm trying Matroska now, seems like it handles timestamping a bit differently. Maybe you could shed some light on different file containers for me? The source files are mp4s, some 2 seconds, some 3 seconds, all h264 aac 1080p15.

Comment: My final command was `ffmpeg -r 15 -f concat -safe 0 -i mylist.txt -c copy videofile.mp4`. Timestamping hass not worked, but since I'll be using the videos for a storyboard editor, I think I'll be fine. I would love to learn more about this though.